Optimal Strategy for Multi Player Coin Game
You are playing a game involving yourself and 4 other players, each one of you starting with \$1000. You have an unfair coin that lands heads $\frac{2}{3}$ of the time and tails $\frac{1}{3}$ of the time.

Over the course of $15$ rounds, players bet an amount of money on whether they think the coin will show up heads or tails, and the winners of each round will divide the pot proportional to their respective bets. For example, if you and another player bet \$100 and \$200 respectively on heads, the other $3$ bet \$100 each on tails, and it comes heads, then you would win \$200 and the other player wins \$400.
What strategy should you pick to maximize your expected earnings over the course of the $15$ rounds in a sustainable matter while bearing in mind the risk you take on?
My Thoughts:
The first question is how often to bet heads and tails. Speaking from an EV standpoint, it makes sense to bet on heads every time as you expect to make a profit in $10$ rounds. However, we expect there to be 10 heads and 5 tails, so maybe it makes sense to bet on tails sometimes? Not sure what the right strategy is there.
Then, the next question is regarding how much money to bet in a round. Preferably, we would want to bet in a way that maximizes our EV in every single round. However, given the fact that we don't know the other player's betting strategies, this seems a little difficult.
Another issue is that if you were to just bet heads every time (and assuming that's the optimal strategy), then each player would do that, resulting in $0$ profit for everyone. So, that tells me that if I want to make a profit, I should also try betting on tails sometimes. This seems like some sort of dynamic Nash equilibrium problem, but I'm unable to come up with a decent heuristic to approximate a better strategy.
Potentially, there could be some application of the Kelly Criterion but the payout isn't constant, meaning the formula doesn't apply as is.

There can't be a strategy with positive expected value, because if everyone used it, then where would the money come from? So it seems like not betting at all is tied for the optimal strategy.

The question might be more interesting if you were required to bet (at least) some fixed amount each time and could not bet both ways in a single round.

I should have been more specific. Yes, you are forced to bet a positive amount each round and have to choose exactly one of heads or tails. I don’t think the answer can be a deterministic strategy. If it’s to bet heads, then everyone bets heads and the new optimal sol becomes to bet 1 on tails to get positive EV (and vice versa if the deterministic sol was to bet tails)

What happens to the pot if everybody bets heads, and it comes tails?

You can view it as the winners getting their bets back plus their share of the losers' bets.  If you bet $b$, the other winners bet a total of $w$ and the losers bet a total of $L$ the return on each dollar you bet is $\frac L{b+w}$ which is a decreasing function of $b$.  If you have to bet, it is better to bet the minimum.  There is an equilibrium for each player to bet heads $\frac 23$ of the time.  If they all bet the same amount the tails bettors will win twice as much, which offsets the winning percentage.  If you bet heads more often, the tails bettors will have a positive expectation because there is more than twice as much losing money bet on heads.
